# Encrypt a string using local public PEM file, decrypt using private key in Azure KayVault

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to write a proof of concept whereby we can encrypt a string using a public key locally and decrypt the string with the associated private key in Azure Key Vault.

I can successfully do this if I encrypt and decrypt using keys directly from Azure KeyVault; however, our use case is that we want to download and store the public key (manually) from Azure KeyVault to encrypt.

In my sample code below, I can encrypt using the local public PEM file. When I try and decode using the associated private key in Azure, I get the error:

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
ErrorCode: BadParameter
```

I get that RSAEncryptionPadding and EncryptionAlgorithm in the encrypt and decrypt may be incompatible, but I don't know where to go from here.

Code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography;


string input = "SomeString";
var encryptStringAsync = EncryptStringAsync(input);

var valenc = encryptStringAsync.Result;

Console.WriteLine(valenc);

var decryptStringAsync = DecryptStringAsync(valenc);

var valueenc = decryptStringAsync.Result;

Console.WriteLine(valueenc);

static async Task<string> EncryptStringAsync(string input)
{
    byte[] inputAsByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

    using (RSA rsa = GetRSAFromPemFile())
    {
        byte[] encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(inputAsByteArray, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
    }

    RSA GetRSAFromPemFile()
    {
        string publicKey = File.ReadAllText("C:\\temp\\20231117.pem");

        var rsaPublicKey = RSA.Create();
        rsaPublicKey.ImportFromPem(publicKey);

        return rsaPublicKey;
    }
}


static async Task<string> DecryptStringAsync(string input)
{

    string keyVaultName = "xxx";
    string keyVaultUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";
    string keyVaultKeyName = "xxx";
    
    var client = new KeyClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
    KeyVaultKey key = await client.GetKeyAsync(keyVaultKeyName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var cryptoClient = new CryptographyClient(key.Id, new DefaultAzureCredential());
    
    byte[] inputAsByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    DecryptResult decryptResult = await cryptoClient.DecryptAsync(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, inputAsByteArray).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return Encoding.Default.GetString(decryptResult.Plaintext);
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: In `EncryptStringAsync()` you use `RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256`, which corresponds to OAEP with SHA-256 (for OAEP and MGF1 digest), while in `DecryptStringAsync()` `EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep` is used instead, which corresponds to OAEP with SHA-1 (for both digests). For compatibility, the OAEP parameters must be identical. Thus, try e.g. `EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep256`.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately that isn't a valid option. My options are Pkcs1, OaepSHA1, OaepSHA256, OaepSHA384, OaepSHA512

Comment: If `EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep` cannot be changed in `DecryptStringAsync()`, you can achieve compatibility by using `RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1` in `EncryptStringAsync()`. As I said, for compatibility the OAEP parameters must be identical for encryption and decryption.

Comment: that's it. Do you want to create an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I have put my comments as an answer. Thx.

Comment: Can I do the same using powershell? Ie, encrypting locally with a pem file.

Comment: calling rsa.Encrypt() throws `Unhandled exception. System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unknown error (0xc100000d)
   at Interop.BCrypt.BCryptEncryptRsa(SafeBCryptKeyHandle key, ReadOnlySpan`1 source, Span`1 destination, Void* pPaddingInfo, BCryptEncryptFlags dwFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSABCrypt.TryEncrypt(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Span`1 destination, RSAEncryptionPadding padding, Int32& bytesWritten)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Encrypt(ReadOnlySpan`1 data, Span`1 destination, RSAEncryptionPadding padding) ` Unknown error is really hard to debug

Comment: Is there a limit for input string size? The above example works, but if I susbstitute `string input = "SomeString"` with `string input= File.ReadAllText(pathToJson)` it throws above exception

Comment: Apparently, there is such a limit, I'm well above it, so this explains the error for me. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42097/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-the-plaintext-message-for-rsa-oaep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using RSA with OAEP, the OAEP parameters for decryption must correspond to those for encryption. This applies in particular to the two digests, the OAEP digest and the MGF1 digest. Another parameter is the OAEP label, which is generally always left blank. For RSA with OAEP see [RFC 8017, 7.1. RSAES-OAEP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-7.1).

In the posted code, however, the digests differ for encryption and decryption. In `EncryptStringAsync()`, [`RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaencryptionpadding.oaepsha256?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-rsaencryptionpadding-oaepsha256) is used, which applies SHA-256 for both digests, while in `DecryptStringAsync()` [`EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.keys.cryptography.encryptionalgorithm.rsaoaep?view=azure-dotnet#azure-security-keyvault-keys-cryptography-encryptionalgorithm-rsaoaep) is used (see also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/about-keys-details#wrapkeyunwrapkey-encryptdecrypt)), which applies SHA-1 for both digests.

The fix is therefore to use [`RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaencryptionpadding.oaepsha1?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-rsaencryptionpadding-oaepsha1) in `EncryptStringAsync()` or alternatively [`EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep256`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.keys.cryptography.encryptionalgorithm.rsaoaep256?view=azure-dotnet#azure-security-keyvault-keys-cryptography-encryptionalgorithm-rsaoaep256) in `DecryptStringAsync()` so that the same OAEP parameters are used on both sides.